# What is the difference between Array.prototype.reverse and Array.reverse in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototype

The question I have deals with an application of adding a new method to the existing **String constructor**. In Object Oriented Program for Javascript by Stoyan Stefanov, there is an example of using the **Array constructor's .reverse()** method to create one for the **String constructor.** Here is the example:

```
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
     return Array.prototype.reverse.apply(this.split('')).join('');
}
```

I thought the **.reverse()** method of Array belonged directly to the object of Array. In fact, when I try to do the second bit of code with this statement:,

```
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
     return Array.reverse.apply(this.split('')).join(''); //WITHOUT the .prototype
}

var rev = "karunesh".reverse(); //applying the code here
```

I get an error in the Firebug Console stating: *"TypeError: missing argument 0 when calling function Array.reverse"*. That does not make any sense to me.

And of course, if I add back in the **.prototype**, it works perfectly fine.

Also, if is the case that I have to call upon prototype to access the **.reverse() method** from the **Array object,** then is it the case that I have to do that for any built-in object in Javascript?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: It might have something to do with how you're setting up the array. This should work instead: `return this.split("").reverse().join("");`

Comment: Why would you expect that to work? You need to learn what the `prototype` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it the case that I have to call upon prototype to access the .reverse() method from the Array object

No. To access a method on an object, just access it with dot notation. What you want to do is simply

```
return this.split('').reverse().join('');
```

That is just what [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (or `call`) does:

```
var arr = this.split('');
return arr.reverse.apply(arr).join('');
```

and finally `arr.reverse === Array.prototype.reverse` since that's where `Array` objects do inherit from. You are not accessing the `reverse` method on the `Array` constructor function object itself, you are to access the property that all `Array` *instances* share - via their prototype. Yet you hardly will ever need to use the prototype object explicitly, that's only when you're dealing with objects that are not `Array` instances (do not share the prototype) like `arguments` objects or `NodeList`s.

> `TypeError: missing argument 0 when calling function Array.reverse`. That does not make any sense to me.

`Array.reverse` is a non-standard [`Array` generic method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods) which is only available in Firefox. It's purpose is to simplify the construct of applying Array prototype methods on other objects, and it does take the array-like object as it's first parameter. An example:

```
Array.reverse([0, 1]) // [1, 0]
```

which is equivalent to

```
Array.prototype.reverse.apply([0, 1]);
```

However, you were doing

```
Array.reverse.apply([…]/*, undefined*/)
```

which is calling the `Array.reverse` function with the array for the (irrelevant) [`this` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and no actual argument, equivalent to

```
Array.prototype.reverse.apply(undefined)
```

and that throws the rightful exception.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.reverse` is undefined (at least in Chrome 29) - `Array.prototype.reverse` is a function that will reverse the order of the "iterable" it is called on.

The key thing to note here is that `Array` is not a class like you would have in Java - rather it is a *constructor*:

```
[].constructor === Array;
// true
```

The `prototype` property of `Array` is actually what is providing the behavior to any particular instance of `Array`:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf([]) === Array.prototype;
// true

// Bad idea, just for an example
var guys = ['Tom', 'Harry', 'Richard'];
Array.prototype.exclaim = function() {
    return this.join(", ") + "?!?!?!";
}; 
guys.exclaim();
// Tom, Harry, Richard?!?!?!
```

The key here is that JavaScript uses a prototype-based object-oriented pattern, rather than the classical pattern you are more likely familiar with.  Instead of having "classes" which contain all the behaviors, but which are distinct from instances, JavaScript has objects, which can be the "prototypes" of other objects, providing data and behavior to the child objects.

```
// Totally licit OO pattern in JavaScript
var prototypeClass = {
    method1: function() { console.log("Hello from method 1!"); },
    method2: function() { console.log("Hello from method 2!"); },
    classData: 42 
};

var prototypeInstance = Object.create(prototypeClass);

prototypeInstance.method1()  // Hello from method 1!
prototypeInstance.classData  // 42

// And you can modify the class after
// instantiating instances and the changes
// will be picked up by the instances
prototypeClass.happyPrimes = "Don't they teach recreational mathematics anymore?";

prototypeInstance.happyPrimes // The quote from 42
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, `Array.reverse === Array.prototype.reverse` is `false` in Firefox.

Comment: I don't quite understand why Array.reverse exists in Firefox.

Comment: @ takteek : surely to ease the use of apply on array functions : instead of doing Array.prototypye.xxxx.apply(...) you can do Array.xxx.apply(...). (Same for call). But since it's not standard, this is quite a useless effort...